# How to read complex XML using linq C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to read a xml file... when it is simple xml it works perfectly, but when it is complex xml this does not work. For example:

Simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FILE>
  <CLIENTS>
    <CLIENT>
      <NAME>William</NAME>
      <AGE>25</AGE>
    </CLIENT>

    <CLIENT>
      <NAME>John</NAME>
      <AGE>31</AGE>
    </CLIENT>
  </CLIENTS>
</FILE>
```

C#:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(path);
var clientNodes = from clt in document.Descendants("CLIENTS") select clt;
//This works and "clientNodes" has values for clients node
```

But when I want to load more complex xml, the query from the file is empty

Complex XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<SII:RESPONSE xmlns:SII="http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema">

<SII:RESPONSE_STATUS>
    <SII:STATE>1</SII:STATE>
</SII:RESPONSE_STATUS>
<SII:RESPONSE_CONTENT>
    <CREATED_BY>
        <ID>233</ID>
        <NAME>Sophy</NAME>
    </CREATED_BY>
    <CLIENT>
        <NAME>William</NAME>
        <AGE>25</AGE>
    </CLIENT>
    <CLIENT>
        <NAME>John</NAME>
        <AGE>25</AGE>
    </CLIENT>
</SII:RESPONSE_CONTENT>
```

C#:

```
XDocument documentoXML = XDocument.Load(path);
var simpleNodes = from clt in document.Descendants(XName.Get("SII", "RESPONSE_CONTENT")) select clt;
```

//This does not work and "simpleNodes" has no values :(

Help pls!

Comment: You should try a proper XML parser for this. LINQ will only work as long as you do not have any escaped control characters or similar stuff. The good ones can even verify if it follows a proper shema.

Comment: @Christopher: which "escaped control characters" do you refer to? Some numeric character reference (&#xnnnn;)? I never had problems parsing these using LINQ. Andyou **can** validate against a schema; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.extensions.validate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Schema_Extensions_Validate_System_Xml_Linq_XDocument_System_Xml_Schema_XmlSchemaSet_System_Xml_Schema_ValidationEventHandler_System_Boolean_

Comment: @KlausGütter: Because System.XML.Shema.Validate wich works on a X(ML)Document is part of a proper XML parser. Rather then parsing the whole stuff with LINQ. So thanks for the example of a proper XML parser. Just why does it sound like you disagree with me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be

```
XName.Get("RESPONSE_CONTENT", "http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema")
```

or easier:

```
XNamespace sii = "http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema";
```

and then

```
document.Descendants(sii + "RESPONSE_CONTENT")
```